# sinatra or Rails app: simplify classification of results

Tags: sinatra

I have a Sinatra app, but I guess this question would be valid also in RoR. I the app, a user can see his spendings, by order of `date`, `amount` or `name`.

I the controller, I have 3 `get` routes corresponding to those possible orders (default is per date).

This means that when the user selects "per amount" for example, the request is sent to the server and then to the database with a corresponding sql query. Although it works, I'm wondering whether this is the most effecient way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `params` hash to make this more maintainable for you.

```rb
get '/spendings' do 
  @spendings = Spending.where(user_id: current_user.id)

  # Make date the default sort
  sort = 'date'
  sort = params[:sort] if params[:sort].in?(['amount', 'name'])

  @spendings = @spendings.order(sort)
end
```

The urls you have to use are then something like

```html
example.com/spendings?sort=date
example.com/spendings?sort=amount
example.com/spendings?sort=name
```

Comment: Thanks Eyeslandic. That does clear up the code. However, this still sends the request back to the database. I was looking for a way to store the results in a hash server side or in javascript and reorder it upon request, rather than sending the request to the DB each time.

Comment: Storing it in a hash server side doesn't save you much, you could look into using some javascript datatables that have sorting included, or use a js frontend framework, vuejs can easily be included to just a part of your website.